# jQuery - search for previous selector relative to current

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a form with 3 sections in it.  Each section has a dedicated div for fairly long contextual help messages regarding the input that has focus.

My question is, if I give each of these help divs a class of "form-tip" and each input that has a tip the class "has-tip", how can I get the tip to always show up in the previous "form-tip" div?

Something like:

```
$('.has-tip').each(focus(function() {
    var tip = $(this).attr('title');
    // Find most recent $('.form-tip') in the DOM and populate it with tip
}));
```

I hope that makes sense... Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If the `.has-tip` is a child of `.form-tip` then you can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) like this:

```
$('.has-tip').each(focus(function() {
    var tip = $(this).attr('title');
    var ft = $(this).closest('.form-tip');
    // Find most recent $('.form-tip') in the DOM and populate it with tip
}));
```

If it's a sibling, you can use [`.prev('.form-tip')`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) or if it's not *immediately* before, then it's [`.prevAll('.form-tip: first')`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

Answer (score 1):

```
var container = $(this).closest('.form-tip')
```

within the .each if I understood properly.